# Linq filter to avoid a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq, linq-to-objects

I am trying to formulate a LINQ query but not a pro at it so whatever I try is not working. I would like to filter the list to get email-ids from below list where score is 0 grouped by the Team Name.

The way I was trying to do it was:

1. Get list of distinct Team Names.
2. Loop through each distinct team name and get the email-ids where score is 0.

```
Team    Name   Score    EmailId  
Hawk    Amy     0       Amy@gmail.com  
Hawk    Aby     0       Aby@gmail.com  
Hawk    Raf     1       Raf@gmail.com  
Hawk    Jay     2       Jay@gmail.com  
Eagle   Blu     0       Blu@gmail.com  
Eagle   Tru     1       Tru@gmail.com
```

I would like to get two lines: `Hawk` and `Amy@gmail.com, Aby@gmail.com` and the next result would be `Eagle` with `Blue@gmail.com`. 
**Is this possible through LINQ and in a single step?**

Comment: `data.Where(x => x.Score == 0).Select(x => new { x.Team, x.EmailId }).GroupBy(x => x.Team)`?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a loop?

Comment: Why group by team? You will end up with 2 records at the most: Hawk, Eagle. Is that what you want?

Comment: "Want to filter the list to get email-ids where score is 0 grouped by the Team Name." actually linq is so cool that it even named the functions like normal people talk ;) [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) and [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8). In your case **get** is called [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I was just trying to find a better way of doing it and avoiding loop. No particular reason.

Comment: @haim770 : It gives me separate lists but how do I get the email-Ids without looping through ?

Comment: your first approach is probably quite readable and easy to maintain :) But I can understand the urge to use a nice linq statement ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're currently doing, but this is how I would do it

```
var result = list.Where(p => p.Score == 0)
                 .Select(p => new{p.Team, p.EmailId})
                 .GroupBy(p => p.Team)
                 .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 3):

> Want to filter the list to get email-ids where score is 0 grouped by the Team Name.

**filter the list to get email-ids where score is 0**

```
var filteredList = list.Where(record => records.Score == 0);
```

**grouped by the Team Name**

```
var groupedByTeamName = filteredList.GroupBy(record => record.Team)
```

this will return an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TRecord, TTeam>>` if I'm not mistaken. `IGrouping<T,K>` is just a list with a `Key` property holding what you grouped by (a Team in this case).

you can of course call them in cascade-style:

```
list.Where(record => records.Score == 0).GroupBy(record => record.Team);
```

but debugging will be a little harder as you will have to select the code and quick watch parts of the sentence. And there are times this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> Want to filter the list to get email-ids where score is 0 grouped by the Team Name.

Is this a difficult way to say:

> I want all emails of team-members that are in teams that didn't score?

Group your data into "Teams with their players and their scores"; Keep only those teams that have only zero scores and extract the emails from the players.

For this we use the [overload of GroupBy with aKeySelector and aResultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__)

```
var emailsOfPlayersInTeamsWithZeroScor = myInput.GroupBy

    // keySelector: the team
    .GroupBy(inputItem => inputItem.Team,

    // ResultSelector: from every Team with its players and scores
    // make sequences of emails of players and check if there is a score at all
    (team, players) => new
    {
        // not interested in the team

        // remember if all scores are zero
        HasOnlyZeroScore = players.All(player.Score == 0),

        // remember all emails of the players in the team
        PlayerEmails = players.Select(player => player.Email),
    })

    // keep only the items with a zero score
    .Where(team => team.HasOnlyZeroScore)

    // and select the lists of emails per team as one big list:
    .SelectMany(team => team.PlayerEmails);
```

Simple comme bonjour!